# ADF V2 - ADLS to SQL Server On prem, does column order matter?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've been trying to move data from a flat file in ADLS (Azure Data Lake Store) to a SQL Server On Prem, using purely ADLS and SQL Server Datasets, I thought that the TabularTranslator Property was going to help to map the columns and ignore the order of how they are in the flat file. doing something like this

```
{
    "source": {
        "type": "AzureDataLakeStoreSource"
    },
    "sink": {
        "type": "SqlSink",
        "writeBatchSize": 10000
    },
    "enableStaging": false,
    "cloudDataMovementUnits": 0,
    "translator": {
        "type": "TabularTranslator",
        "columnMappings": "ColA: ColA, ColB:ColB"
    }
}
```

However it looks like the order matters, and TabularTranslator might only work for SQL Server and Azure SQL databases, is there anyway to map these columns without having to change the column order of my target?

The error I'm getting is a truncation error because it is trying to insert ColB data into ColA in my destination

**More details**
In other words, I have the following source and target...

**Source**: File.tsv

ColA ColB

"codeA"    1

"codeB"    2

"codeC"    3

**Target**: SQL Server table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      ColB           |     ColB         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|                     |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Looks like the data coming from ColA tries to get inserted into ColB and then I got the following:

***"ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDataValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column 'ColB' contains an invalid value 'codeA';. Cannot convert 'codeA'; to type 'Double';.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'"***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tabular translator is not needed, I've only used it when moving data from ADLS to a warehouse using Polybase, but I think this is not supported for on-premises databases.

Take a look at the documentation when using a data lake as a source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-store#copy-activity-properties

It should work completely fine without a tabular translator in your case.

Hope this helped!!

Comment: Thanks Martin, you are right, the Tabular translator is not needed, I added more details to my original question, I guess that what I was trying to ask was if there was a way of mapping these columns out without requiring to change the order of my columns in my destination table in SQL, I already changed the order of my destination table and it worked, however  sometimes it is not very elegant for users as the flat files order may not make visually sense

Comment: I see. Still, if the names of the columns in the tsv file are the same as those in the sql server table, data factory should be able to map them without it (and then the order doesnt matter), as seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping

Comment: Agreed, I was expecting ADF to handle that but looks like I'm missing something. Are you able to do that? for example have a flat file with ColA, ColB and a target sql server table with ColB, ColC and move data from ADLS to SQL Serve on Prem without problems?

Comment: No, you can have ColB, ColA in a flat file and ColA, ColB in the sql server table and move data without problems, no matter the order. If the names are different then yes, you need to use the tabular translator to map each column from source to sink, but the documentation doesnt mention a specific order to do that.

Comment: I understand but that's not what's happening, my column names are the same and order matters :( so looks like I'm missing something, documentation is not clear on that particular use case

Comment: By the way your info was pretty useful, thanks for the late response and +1 and answer